# Как сохранить текст из окна батника в txt файл?

Tags: cmd, bat, ffmpeg

Код батника (определяю разрешение видеофайла):

```html
@echo off
for /f "tokens=3,4 delims=x" %%a in ('ffmpeg -i vidov_ska4ali_1.mp4 -hide_banner -v verbose ^| findstr /C:"Stream.*Video"') do set "width=%%a" & set "height=%%b"
echo Width: %width% Height: %height%


if not exist output.txt (
    checkresolution.bat > output.txt
)


TIMEOUT /T 100 /NOBREAK

pause
```

Выдаёт:
[image]

Сохраняет только это:

```
Width:  Height: 

Время ожидания 100 сек., нажмите CTRL+C для выхода ... 99 98 97
Завершить выполнение пакетного файла [Y(да)/N(нет)]?
```

Да, я знаю что сохраняет только текст "рождённый" батником а не от ffmpeg, но как сохранить так же и текст от ffmpeg в текстовый документ?

Answer (score 0):

так сделал и смог сохранить текст из окна работы батника:

```
ffmpeg -i vidov_ska4ali_1.mp4 -hide_banner 2> filename_Info.txt
```